# Div reload not working

Tags: jquery, html, load

How can I load a specific DIV using `load` in JQuery?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#myDiv').load('some.html #someDiv');
```

Comment: Please specify your problem, your load code seems to be correct. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @hyde when i load that statement my whole page display in '#someDiv'. I want to refresh only the '#myDiv' not the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQueries "load()" function is meant to load data from the server. There is no server here. You will either need to define a URL as specified in the jQuery API, or you need to use .html() to load the HTML from somewhere else in your DOM.

```
$("#myDiv").html($("#someDiv").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You look like you want to replace the HTML of the element.

Do this:

`$('#myelem').html('<strong>Some new HTML content</strong>');`

To copy the HTML content of another element, tweak it:

`$('#myelem').html( $('#otherelem').html() );`